# Можно ли спроектировать Qt dll, которая тянет за собой OpenGL?

Tags: c++, qt, opengl, архитектура, dll

Я хочу создать некий графический движок (основан на `QOpenGL`). Наработки уже есть, если вдруг вам интересно, с ними можно ознакомиться тут: https://github.com/StrawberryAttacks/OpenGLWorldEngine

Сейчас планирую перестроить его, в корне изменив архитектуру. Будет большая фабрика *WorldEngineFactory*, от которой наследуются три фабрики: *SkyBoxFactory*, *Object3DFactory*, *LightFactory*. Классы: *SkyBox* - куб, отвечающий за окружение (пространство, в котором будет всё находиться), *Object3D*, экземпляры которого являются моделями на сцене, *Light*, экземпляром которого будет источник освещения (планирую добавить разные типы).

Мой движок - это динамическая библиотека. Но получится ли у меня сделать `Qt dll`, которая в себе бы подключала OpenGL? Я хочу, чтобы, при создании нового проекта, не нужно было в него загружать OpenGL и движок, а достаточно было бы динамически загрузить только движок. Существует ли такая возможность?

Критика архитектуры приветствуется, это мой первый проект, который я пытаюсь построить правильно с точки зрения ООП, поэтому заранее спасибо за любые предложения.

Или лучше всё перевести в статику? Избавиться от полиморфизма, заменив необходимость реализации интерфейса на compile time **requirements** (с++ 20) ? Как-никак, виртуальные функции - дорогое удовольствие, тем более все типы данных будут известны на момент компиляции (если, конечно, пользователь движка не захочет сделать в игре что-то вроде "выберите создаваемый объект"). Я в замешательстве!

Comment: Не очень понятно, что вы имеете в виду. OpenGL — это просто API, а реализации этого API предоставляются драйверами видеокарт

Comment: @andreymal , я говорю про прослойку между пользователем и самой библиотекой. В репозитории есть пример использования движка (https://github.com/StrawberryAttacks/OpenGLWorldEngine/tree/main/usage%20example)